# How match end of a string not catch plus

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a regular expression like below:

```
 if (string.match(/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*\,?\s*([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*(mon|tues|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)/ig)) {
    string = string.replace(/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*\,?\s*([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*(mon|tues|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)/ig, "$3 $1 , $3 $2")
}
```

to catch the following patterns:

1- 8-20      15-19 sat,

2- 8-10    14-18  tues

3- 8-15    18-20 fri  metro

BUT NOT these case: 
" 8-10    14-20  tues+fri+sat-fr"  OR  "8-10    14-20  tues+fri"

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: save regexp into reusable variable.

Comment: You don't have to check a pattern with the match method before a replacement. Use only String.prototype.replace (that finds and replace)

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/bn3zvamn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regex : https://regex101.com/r/yiDfKz/6/

```
([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*\,?\s*([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*(mon|tues|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)([^+]|$)
```

`([^+]|$)` ==> except `+` character or endline (need multiline flag)

or this regex : https://regex101.com/r/yiDfKz/4/

```
([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*\,?\s*([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\s*(mon|tues|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)([, ]|$)
```

`([, ]|$)` ==> comma, slash or endline (need multiline flag)

or finally this more compact regex : https://regex101.com/r/yiDfKz/7

```
(\d+-\d+)\s*,?\s*(\d+-\d+)\s*(mon|tues|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?!\+)
```

using negative lookahead `(?!\+)` and using `[0-9]` instead of \d`

Comment: If you use a negated character class, the pattern will fail at the end of the string. https://regex101.com/r/yiDfKz/3

Comment: You can use: `(?:[^+]|$)` or a negative lookahead `(?!\+)`

Comment: And remove unnecessary escapes in front of `,` and `-`.

Comment: Thanks, I have change the regex